Do You Need A Mezonos For Taanis Bechorim?
One of the ways for firstborns to eat on Erev Pesach is to hear somebody make a Siyum. If you hear the Siyum, but didn't eat a Mezonos, and you're a Bechor - can you eat or not?

Are you asking about mezonos vs shehakol?

@DoubleAA - no, I am talking about food overall

My shul, with the approval of the Rabbi, used to have macaroons for the siyum.
Then their standards went down and they switched to baby fingers - I guess they figured if they can't have something people will actually enjoy, might as well save money.
Both types of cookies are shehakol.

Baby fingers are an upgrade.

In Yalkut Yosef Pesach Volume 2 Page 758 he brings OC Siman 568:1 which says, נדר להתענות יום זה ושכח ואכל משלים תעניתו והוא הדין אם היה תענית חלום או שהיה תענית צבור או שהיה יום ידוע לו להתענות כיום שמת בו אביו או רבו אבל אם נדר להתענות יום א' או שני ימים וכשהתחיל להתענות שכח ואכל כזית איבד תעניתו וחייב לצום יום אחר, "If one takes a vow to fast on a certain day, and he then forgets and eats, he should still complete the fast. This applies to dream fasts, public fasts, or days that he knows to fast on like the day that his father or rabbi died. But if he vows to fast one or two days, and he forgets and eats a kezayit, he has "lost" his fast, and he must fast another day." He proves from here that if one has less than a Kazyit of anything on a Taanit Neder (fruit, vegetables, mezonot, etc) then he hasn't broken his fast, so the same applies to Taanit Bechorot than one must have a kazyit so that the fast is broken (look at commentaries on Shulchan Aruch). In Shu"t Minchat Yitzchak 9:45 he also says to have a kazyit of anything.

I don't think that answered my question. My question is do i need to hear another Siyum, or am i permitted to eat right now?

Ya Sorry, in the footnote, he says that if the bechor did not eat a kazyit of fruit or mezonot at the syium and then ones goes to his house, he is not allowed to eat and would need to hear another syium since the Taanit Bechorot is still on the bechor since he didn't eat, he brings Shu"t Vayivarech David OC 54 who says the same thing
